# integrating a Green's function for a damped harmonic oscillator

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have the following integrand:

```
int = Sin[Sqrt[-g^2 + omega^2]*(t - tp)]*Exp[-g*(t - tp)]*A*Exp[-(tp - t0)^2/sigma^2]*Cos[Omega*tp]/Sqrt[-g^2 + omega^2]
```

and am trying to integrate it with:

```
Integrate[int, {tp, 0, t}, Assumptions -> {g > 0, omega > 0, Omega > 0, A > 0, sigma > 0, t > 0, t0>0}]
```

but *Mathematica* is not able to do it (I have tried to do this with no assumptions as well). Maple does the integration in under a second and returns a solution (which can be expressed in terms of the Erf functions).

Is there a way to help *Mathematica* calculate this integral?

... and just to note, the result of the integration is a solution of damped harmonic oscillator, driven by a force:

```
A*Exp[-(t - t0)^2/sigma^2]*Cos[Omega*t]
```

Comment: the small omega is the natural frequency, while the large omega (i.e. Omega) is the frequency of the drive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This takes about 30 seconds to evaluate on my computer:

```
 Integrate[int // TrigToExp // Expand, {tp, 0, t}, 
  Assumptions -> {omega > g > Omega > 0, A > 0, sigma > 0, t > 0, t0 > 0}]
```

Also if it is a solution of a linear ODE (with constant coefficients?) then perhaps it can be found directly with `DSolve`.

Comment: thanks for taking a look at this. Doing TrigToExp, and Expanding does indeed work! I should note that you added extra assumptions in your answer, but going back to the assumptions that I specified in my question also works.